# Converting List of String to Dictionary of Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

Initial input:-

```
elements = ['description:',
            '- Hello, Welcome',
            '- Welcome back',
            'type:',
            '- new',
            '- existing',
            'updated_at:',
            '- 2017-12-20 09:06:20.599415000 Z',
            '- 2017-12-20 09:08:50.398076080 Z'
]
```

For context, I want to convert the `list` above to a `dict` of a `dict`. I am still learning Python so my explanation might not be good.

If there is a colon in the string, then it will be used as the key. Please refer to the text below as the ideal output.

Ideal output:-

```
{
    'description': {
        'before': 'Hello, Welcome', 
        'after': 'Welcome back'
    }, 
    'type': {
        'before': 'new', 
        'after': 'existing'
    }, 
    'updated_at': {
        'before': '2017-12-20 09:06:20.599415000 Z', 
        'after': '2017-12-20 09:08:50.398076080 Z'
    }
}
```

This is currently what I have. However, it will only work for line 1. The rest will not produce what I wanted. Currently, this only processes one element. I want it to be able to process a whole column as well.

```
elements = df['details'][3].split('\n')[1:]
clean_elements = []
for element in elements:
    if ':' not in element:
        clean_elements[-1] = clean_elements[-1] + element
    else:
        clean_elements.append(element)
clean_elements

data = {}

for element in clean_elements:
    element = element.split(': ')
    data[element[0]] = element[1]
```

Comment: please add your input as text not images, also you've tagged pandas but don't seem to be asking for it or using it, can you clarify?

Comment: Where are the keys `'before'` and `'after'` coming from?

Comment: @Manakin the input is from one of the columns in a row in the df.

Comment: @Axe319 sorry if i didn't mention this, if you look at the pattern of the input, there is always 2 dashes in two lines respectively after the key, so in this case the 'before' and 'after' are not here but I want to hard code it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to transform your initial input to your desired output. I don't knot the contents of your dataframe, so I'm assuming here that `elements` contains the initial input list as in the screenshot in your post.

```
elements = ['description:', '- Hello, Welcome', '- Welcome back',
            'type:', '- new', '- existing',
            'updated_at:', '- 2017-12 09:06:20.599415999 Z', '- 2017-12 09:08:50.398076080 Z']

output = {}
element_iter = iter(elements)
for e in element_iter:
    if e.endswith(':'):
        before = next(element_iter).lstrip('- ')
        after = next(element_iter).lstrip('- ')
        output[e.rstrip(':')] = {'before': before, 'after': after}

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your initial input is actually a list, and that you'd always have a syntax in which there's a key, then old, then new value (values containing a dash and a space and key containing a colon) then you could just loop through each 3 elements like this:

```
initial_input = ['a:','- X', '- Y', 'b:', '- C', '- D', 'c:', '- qweqwe', '- asdasd']
result = {}
for i in range(0, len(initial_input), 3):
    key_name = initial_input[i][:-1]
    before_value = initial_input[i+1][2:]
    after_value = initial_input[i+2][2:]
    result[key_name] = {'before': before_value, 'after': after_value}

print result
# {'a': {'after': 'Y', 'before': 'X'}, 'c': {'after': 'asdasd', 'before': 'qweqwe'}, 'b': {'after': 'D', 'before': 'C'}}
```

If the initial input is a string, you'd need to parse it to a list using the `json` module beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential solution using [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
d = {elements[i].strip(':'):{'before': elements[i+1].strip('- '),
                             'after':  elements[i+2].strip('- ')}
     for i in range(0, len(elements), 3)}
```

[out]

```
{'description': {'before': 'Hello, Welcome', 'after': 'Welcome back'},
 'type': {'before': 'new', 'after': 'existing'},
 'updated_at': {'before': '2017-12 09:06:20.599415999 Z',
  'after': '2017-12 09:08:50.398076080 Z'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `deque` from the collections module to "rotate" `before` and `after`. This makes it easier to add more later and you're not hardcoding too much.

```
from collections import deque
elements = ['description:',
            '- Hello, Welcome',
            '- Welcome back',
            'type:',
            '- new',
            '- existing',
            'updated_at:',
            '- 2017-12-20 09:06:20.599415000 Z',
            '- 2017-12-20 09:08:50.398076080 Z'
]
my_dict = dict()
# This assumes the first element will always be a key
current_key = None
inner_keys = deque(['before', 'after'])
for element in elements:
    if element.endswith(':'):
        current_key = element.rstrip(':')
        my_dict[current_key] = dict()
    else:
        my_dict[current_key][inner_keys[0]] = element.lstrip('- ')
        inner_keys.rotate()
print(my_dict)
```

A `deque` is basically a collection that you can rotate the elements on.
So calling `rotate()` on it when it has the elements `['before', 'after']` changes their order to `['after', 'before']` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

So the main idea here is to loop over the `elements`.

When you find a string that ends with `:`, then you know it should be the key for your dictionary.

After words the next two items in the loop will become the `before` and `after` sections of the dictionary.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
current_key = None

out = defaultdict(list)
for elem in elements: 
    # in element ends with : it is a new key
    if elem.strip().endswith(':'):
        current_key = elem.strip(':')
        continue

    assert current_key is not None

    out[current_key].append(elem[2:])
```

we now have the data in the following format:

```
{
    'description': [
        'Hello, Welcome', 
        'Welcome back'
    ], 
    'type': [
        'new', 
        'existing'
   ], 
    'updated_at': [
        '2017-12-20 09:06:20.599415000 Z', 
        '2017-12-20 09:08:50.398076080 Z'
    ]
}
```

so in order to map it into the dictionary format you wanted we just iterate over the items and convert it:

```
for key, value in out.items(): 
    out[key] = dict(zip(['before', 'after'], value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `itertools.groupby`. This makes it easier to handle a varied number of subkeys per main key:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
elements = ['description:', '- Hello, Welcome', '- Welcome back', 'type:', '- new', '- existing', 'updated_at:', '- 2017-12-20 09:06:20.599415000 Z', '- 2017-12-20 09:08:50.398076080 Z']
r = [list(b) for _, b in gb(elements, key=lambda x:x.startswith('- '))]
d = {r[i][0][:-1]:dict(zip(['before', 'after'], [k[2:] for k in r[i+1]])) for i in range(0, len(r), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{
    "description": {
       "before": "Hello, Welcome",
       "after": "Welcome back"
    },
    "type": {
       "before": "new",
       "after": "existing"
    },
    "updated_at": {
       "before": "2017-12-20 09:06:20.599415000 Z",
       "after": "2017-12-20 09:08:50.398076080 Z"
    }
}
```